# Adding a new column to a df is not carrying over to a shallow copy of the df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, shallow-copy

I have a very simple df, which I'm going to make a shallow copy of.

```
# assign dataframe
old_df = pd.DataFrame({'values': [10, 20, 30, 40]})

# shallow copy
copy_df = old_df.copy(deep=False)
```

I understand that in a shallow copy, the changes made to one should carry over to the original. So if I create a new column (change) to the copy_df, I'd expect the change to be made to the old_df as well.

I tried creating a new column in two methods.

```
# method 1
copy_df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
# method 2 
copy_df['new_col'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
```

My expected result is as follows:

```
>>> old_df
   values  new_col
0      10        0
1      20        0
2      30        0
3      40        0
```

But what I get, from both methods, is the original, unchanged df:

```
>>> old_df
   values
0      10
1      20
2      30
3      40
```

I would like to ask why the change I made to the shallow copy is not carrying over to the original.

Answer (score 1):

This is the expected behaviour now after pandas v1.4: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/47703

Answer (score 1):

> I understand that in a shallow copy, the changes made to one should carry over to the original. So if I create a new column (change) to the copy_df, I'd expect the change to be made to the old_df as well.

Yes, this is true for all existing columns (`Series`) before copying but if you create new columns, they will be added only on the current `DataFrame` because both share the reference to the existing columns.

```
# Create new column
copy_df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]  # or copy_df['new_col'] = [0, 0, 0, 0]
print(old_df)

# Output
   values
0      10
1      20
2      30
3      40
```

```
# Modify existing column
copy_df.loc[[1, 2], 'values'] = 0
print(old_df)

# Output
   values
0      10
1       0
2       0
3      40
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer! Is there a way to create a new column in the shallow copy such that the new column will be created in the original df as well?